# Google Drive Service Account change filename usin API Request

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm trying to perform next API call using PATCH method on a file that is not in a root directory,
[API Call for changing the file name (Picture)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OZZ0C.png)

[The Response (Picture)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Z7a4.png)

The response of above API Call is a File resource with 200 status code, but the file name doesn't changed ;(

I have tried using API v2 and API v3, unfortunately the response is the same. File Name is not changed. For v3 i have used request body {"name": "New Name"}.

Some help please ?
I'm not interested to use any library for perform this call. I'm interested in raw API Call.

Another API Calls for manipulating with files/folders works like expected. Only this call is not working for me.

Sorry for my English,

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does your code look like that doesn't work? Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: @jess this pictures illustrate how the [Bubble.is](https://bubble.is) platform works (no code platform for creating applications).
And how I wrote above, all other API Calls works perfect. Only Rename File using `PATCH https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/[fileId]` and request body in JSON format `{"title":"New Title"}` is executed and returns a correct response but the file title is not changed.

Comment: Have you tried to use the `files.update` method?

Comment: @jess if i'm using `update` method, with the same request body `{"title":"my new tytle"}`, it's update file's content but not title :/

Comment: @jess screen: ![captured screen](https://i.imgur.com/HhXc0wa.png "Screen Google Drive")